# how to get username using perl template toolkit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I have problem with getting username form windows system. I tried using getlogin function in perl and printing it printing my user name , but my problem is how can I access this username in template toolkit. I tried like this

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use warnings;
 use strict;
 use Data::Dumper; 
   use XML::Simple;
 use Template;
  my $username = getlogin || getpwuid($<) || "veeru";

   my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $xml->XMLin("data.xml", ForceArray=>['dat','employee','experience']);
  print $username;

 my $template = Template->new();
my $filename = 'output1.tex';
  $template->process(\*DATA, $data, $filename)
|| die "Template process failed: ", $template->error(), "\n";

system( "pdflatex $filename" );
  __DATA__
 \documentclass[a4paper,leqno,twoside]{article}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \begin{document}

 Issued by {Name}
 \issuedby{ [% username %] }

 % Document title. Use \doctitleShort{} to insert a shorter title in the header.
 \doctitle{employee information of thie"scr"company}
 \doctitleShort{\@doctitle}

[% FOREACH comp IN company %]
[% comp.name %] 
[% comp.location%]
employeedata:
[% FOREACH employee IN comp.domain.java.employee %]

[% employee.name %][% employee.number %]

[% FOREACH obj IN data%]

[% FOREACH beha IN obj.employee %]

[% IF beha.number == employee.number && beha.name == employee.name %] 

 [% beha.address %],

  [% LAST %]
 [% END %]
   [% END %]
 [% END %]
 [% END %]
 [% END %]
  [% END %]
 \end{document}
```

but its not printing username in pdf , it printing username on console, so I did mistake in accessing username variable in template process. please tell me how to use that username variable in template, how to print that in pdf.

my second problem is

```
\doctitle{employee information of thie"scr"company}
```

in the above line document title is written in template process, I need to access title from perl code how to do this.can any one help me because this my first time using template process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hashref that you pass to the template (i.e. `$data`), you need to include any variables that you use in your template. The variables in your template must have a corresponding key in the hashref with the value that you want to use.

So for `username`:

```
$data->{username} = $username;
$template->process(\*DATA, $data, $filename);
```

Similarly, for the `doctitle`, you can set it in your perl code (and thus be able to access it):

```
$data->{doctitle} = 'employee information of thie"scr"company';
```

...and use it in your template:

```
\doctitle{[% doctitle %]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the API documentation of process subroutine [here](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template.html#method_process). As you can see the second argument is a hash reference. All you have to do is to add username, document title, and data.xml to that hash.